# Java Dates and Standard Formats

Tags: java, date

As per [this C# code from Mircrosoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) there is a standard date format such as this:

```
//       R: Sun, 15 Jun 2008 21:15:07 GMT
```

My C# code uses "r" like so:

```
webRequest.Date.ToUniversalTime().ToString("r")
```

How can I create a standard date format like this in Java?

I have this so far:

```
this.timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z").format(new Date());
```

But, I don't know if I should try to write something that will match it or if there is a better way.  My fear is that I will make a mistake and certain dates won't work.

Comment: Whenever one uses "Java" and "datetime" in the same breath, the third-party Joda-time comes to my mind. As you might see from http://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html, joda-time will read and write the ISO8601 standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I create a standard date format like this in Java?

Look at [the documentation for the `r` format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#RFC1123):

> The custom format string is "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'". When this standard format specifier is used, the formatting or parsing operation always uses the invariant culture.
>
> [...] Therefore, the application must convert the date and time value to UTC before it performs the formatting operation

So you translate that custom format string into `SimpleDateFormat`, *and make sure you specify the time zone (UTC) and locale (US English is close enough to the invariant culture):

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'",
                                         Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String text = format.format(date);
```

That's if you want to match the format from .NET's `r` format. Personally I'd go with an ISO-8601 format instead, e.g.

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
                                         Locale.US);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```